# Android Application looks like iphone

Tags: android

I came across this app and I wonder how was it developed on android (Cause it looks so much like an iphone app), see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvuku.jpg).

Anyone have any idea how to accomplish that type of look on Android?

Comment: It also looks like an Android app.

Comment: It also looks like a *mobile* app. It's not that you have many design options that look nice on such screens.

Answer (score 3):

That's just a matter of styling after all. In general, I would consider it to be discouraged to make your Android app look like an iPhone app. Every platform has its own UX standards, and Android's standards are different from iPhone's. That quite obviously also reflects in the user interface.

Anyhow, you may want to read [this article about Android themes and styles](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/). It should get you going with defining own widget styles and stateful drawables to implement custom buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This app obviously uses customized **ListViews**, **ButtonView** on the bottom of the screen.

Theses are pretty much standard and common in android apps.

Comment: Is there a tutorial you can point me to which describes how to customize ListView and ButtonView

Comment: I think he means `Button`, there is no `ButtonView`. A Button is just a text view that uses stateful drawables. You may want to refer to my article about Android styling, which I posted as an answer.

Comment: can you give me a link to your styling article i cant seem to find it

Comment: woops, yeah i meant a Button, there is no ButtonView :p

Comment: It is new material.io design from Android - in this case Bottom Navigation Bar https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html - you also may find more about in Android developer guides. You are right it looks feels more like iPhone apps since Android had in the past more side sliding menues.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to create custom components:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html